# Understanding a Sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I am modifying some shell script and came across this command.

```
sed -i "s@demo.testcase.com@$hostname@g" configuration.xml
```

I searched and found out the sed with s option is just a substitution. And the g at the end stands for global. But I can't find what @ symbol are for.

Can anybody explain the above command to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol immediately following `s` is the command/argument delimiter. Traditionally, `/` is the most commonly used but it can be other symbols, like `@` as well.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, the creator of the file probably uses @ because sometimes he wants to substitute path names. This way he can leave the / (slash) for what they are. Thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Tcanarchy, yep, it's way handier than escaping every slash!

Comment: Do you know what the -i stands for?

Comment: @Tcanarchy, a quick peek at man pages would suggest in-place editing of file.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to replace this:

```
/some data/
```

with this:

```
/some other/data
```

You can do this and escape the `/`

```
sed "s/\/some data\//\/some other\/data/g"
```

or change the `/` to some else:

```
sed "s@/some data/@/some other/data@g"
```